# Crear una tabla con consulta SQL Server y PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server, array, bootstrap

Hola que tal espero me puedan ayudar, tengo el siguiente array que obtengo de una consulta en SQL Server:

```
 $data = array();

            while($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ejecutar)){
                $num = $fila['NumEmpleado'];
                $nom = $fila['Nombre'];
                $fec = $fila['Fecha'];
                $ent = $fila['Entrada'];
                $sal = $fila['Salida'];
        $data[] = array(
                'NumEmpleado' => $num,
                'Nombre' => $nom,
                'Fecha' => $fec,
                'Entrada' => $ent,
                'Salida' => $sal
        );

    }
```

Esta consulta se muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera acomodar la información en una tabla donde los campos de fechas cambian según el rango que se asigne algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor!! me urge mucho e intentado varios métodos pero no lo consigo. ESPERO PUEDAN AYUDARME AUNQUE SEA COLOCANDO ALGUNAS FUNCIONES O TIPS. Estoy trabajando con Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

No sera la forma mas limpia pero puedes intentar armar una estructura así:

```
$matrizEmpleados = [];
foreach($horario as $e)
{
    if(!isset($matrizEmpleados[$e["NumEmpleado"]])){
        $matrizEmpleados[$e["NumEmpleado"]] = [
            "Nombre" => $e["Nombre"];
            "Horarios" => []
        ];
    };
    $matrizEmpleados[$e["NumEmpleado"]]["Horarios"][$e["Fecha"]] = [
        "Entrada" => $e["Entrada"],
        "Salida" => $e["Salida"] 
    ];
}
```

Esto debería darte una estructura así:

```
[
    Nombre => Empleado 1,
    Horarios => [
        "22/04/2019" => [
            "Entrada" => "08:00",
            "Salida" => "17:00"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Asumiendo que ese listado de fechas es lineal y que es corto, puedes hacer un listado con DateTime digamos de 3 días antes y 3 días después:

```
$hoy = new DateTime();
$columnasDeFecha = [];
$columnasDeFecha[] = $hoy->format('d-m-Y');
for($i = 0; $i < 3 ; i++){
    $columnasDeFecha[] = $hoy->modify(sprintf("+1 day"))->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

Para darte las columnas asi: `['22/04/2019','23/04/2019']`

Con esos datos se puede iterar para crear la vista que necesitas.
Lo mejor seria tratar de armar la estructura desde SQL Server con una vista, pero no si tienes acceso a modificarla.
Espero te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a probar con este código a ver que tal funciona.